# Howto use mod_rewrite & php to create a image thumbnail cache

Tags: php, caching, mod-rewrite

I have been working on a script to generate lower resolution copies of images using PHP. I am struggling with mod_write to execute the PHP script only when the file does not exist

What i currently have (which may be off by a bit, as i have made thousands of attempts today) is the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (900x...|...x900)\.(png|jpe?g|gif)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^(.*;\ )?(window_resolution=(640))(;\ .*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule full/(.*) /responsive/cache/480/responsive/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)(900x...|...x900)\.(png|jpe?g|gif)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^(.*;\ )?(window_resolution=(.*))(;\ .*)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/responsive/cache/%3%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule .* /responsive/resize.php [L]
```

Currently the files are located like this:

```
/responsive/full/photo-900x500.jpg
```

The cache is stored:

```
/responsive/cache/
```

In the following format:

```
/responsive/cache/<resolution>/<original path>
```

Example of where i want the files:

```
/responsive/cache/768/responsive/photo-900x500.jpg
```

Ideally this would be used with something like wordpress where i would make a structure like this

Cache:

```
/cache/
```

Originals:

```
/wp-content/uploads/*
```

Example:

```
/cache/768/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/test.jpg
```

Comment: That's a bit extraneous effort if you want to keep that nested structure and even evaluate cookies. However, first look into the `RewriteLog` to see where your current rules are going wrong.

Comment: It is actually for a "seamless" responsive image design. The browser detects its frame size and sends via a cookie. I use varnish to parse my cookies and direct to specific files typically but i wanted to push it more towards apache so that way it could redirect to a php script to generate if an image is missing (as we have many images uploaded frequently). I was trying to just make an "all in one" setup so i wouldn't have to keep writing custom scripts for thumbnails.

I wil look at RewriteLog! Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the 'full' part of the original url?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of deleting and starting over I came up with this and it seems to work just fine. It will reserve the full file path if i want and allows selection of image sizes via cooke:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} $^
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (900x...|...x900)\.(png|jpe?g|gif)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^(.*;\ )?(ricache_width=(480|640|768|992|1170))(;\ .*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /responsive/cache/%3/responsive/$1

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} $^
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)(900x...|...x900)\.(png|jpe?g|gif)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^(.*;\ )?(ricache_width=(480|640|768|992|1170))(;\ .*)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/responsive/cache/%3%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule .* /responsive/resize.php [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} $^
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

It is missing a 404 (which isnt that big of a deal, i have a backup in PHP but i need to replace it). But at least this is a good starting place that functions! :)